# Visual Studio 2015 Community - All References Broken

Tags: c#, .net, reference, visual-studio-2015

I just installed VS2015 community on my home machines.  On my laptop, it works great.  However I've run into an odd issue on my desktop.  No matter what the reference is, it displays as unable to find (yellow warning symbol).  It doesn't matter what or where it is.  I have tried adding framework references (As basic as System) and references to external API DLLs in the local directory like Protobuf.  NuGet will download packages referenced by projects I am working on and they will also be marked invalid.  The properties for these references does not include a path, even when I specify one.

I'm a develop at work so I understand how to handle these issues generally.  I've tried deleting the references and re-adding them, creating new solutions from scratch, pretty much everything I can think of and I'm out of ideas.

This is a Win7 machine with .NET 4.6.1 installed.  I have tried changing my projects to target framework of 2,4,4.5,4.6, and 4.6.1 (no difference).  This is a C# project if it matters.

Can anyone recommend next steps? Thank you.

Comment: Check your VS settings, mb there is no default directories supplied, or might be broken registry values (were default directories path stores).

Comment: I presume you have tried rebooting the machine?  Have you tried uninstalling VS completely, uninstalling any .NET framework versions listed in add/remove programs, rebooting and reinstalling VS?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue.  Last month I tried to upgrade to Win10 and it didn't work out for me so I rolled it back.  It deleted all the ACL information on all my directories.  Specifically, the access to Microsoft.CSharp.Targets was lost.  I restored that and everything worked again.  Of course, now I have to try and fix every file and directory on my computer so I have access again.  Thanks, Win10!